# How to disable all events using refs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I am using TreeView from Material-ui and there is one text field for searching other items present in the screen. TreeView and Textfield don't have any relation.

**So, when I click on the TreeView node, and type a character in the text field, after one character it's losing its focus.**

So, I have decided to create a ref for Treeview and if the user clicks on elements other than TreeView, it should disable all the events of TreeView.

Is that possible? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeView` supports various keyboard navigation features such as arrow keys moving between nodes and also text characters moving to nodes that contain text starting with the characters typed. In `TreeItem`, the `onKeyDown` event is used and, after processing characters for possible navigation, it [calls event.preventDefault()](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TreeItem/TreeItem.js#L209). This prevents the event from having its default effect of typing in your input field.

You can fix this, by preventing keyDown events from propagating to the TreeItem when focus is on your input by adding `onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to your input as shown below.

Sample Code here:
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-within-treeview-y9goo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @shaluj Can you share your code here or codesandbox link?